# How to select an element with a custom classname with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select a `textarea` element which has a classname `sendMessage` with jQuery:

```
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
```

So how can I add the `classname` of that particular element to this line of code?

Comment: `$("textarea.sendMessage")`?

Comment: Where is the jQuery? And why don't you just add it to this line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class selector is represented by dot (.) like below

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea.sendMessage' });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tx4Lc8a9/295/)**.

You could use simply the class sign (dot) `.`, it will look like :

```
tinymce.init({ selector:'.sendMessage ' });
//or
tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea.sendMessage ' });
```

Snippet:

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea.sendMessage"
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="sendMessage">Congratulations!</textarea>
```